# PHP LOAD DATA INFILE only inserting first row for certain files

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, xampp

I have a .dat file that I've pulled from another application that has many rows of comma delimitated data.  I opened the file with Excel, and saved it as a .csv.  I am able to upload that file without issue to my database using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

But here's where it gets weird.  If I take the original file and try to copy, for example, 20 rows and make a new .csv file, when I upload it to the same database, same table schema, it will only load the first row.  Did Excel do something with my formatting when I saved as a new .csv?  It looks the same to me...I can't see a difference when opening with other text editors.

Here's my SQL for creating a new table for the data to be imported (I first check if the table already exists):

```
// Create table - Table name matches name of file without extension
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $file_name . " (
    history_id INT,
    stream_id INT,
    record_time DATETIME,
    ALEQ FLOAT,
    APEAK FLOAT,
    AFASTSPL FLOAT,
    dose FLOAT,
    color INT
)";
```

Here's my SQL for loading the .csv:

```
// Insert data from uploaded .csv file into table
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $target_file . "' 
        INTO TABLE " . $file_name . "
        FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '''' TERMINATED BY ','
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

Here's what the .csv for the file that does work looks like:

```
1,1,'2014-08-28 07:00:31',35.2,56.0,35.1,0.0000000,0
2,1,'2014-08-28 07:00:31',35.1,56.0,35.4,0.0000000,0
3,1,'2014-08-28 07:00:31',35.1,56.0,35.2,0.0000000,0
4,1,'2014-08-28 07:00:31',35.3,56.0,35.0,0.0000000,0
5,1,'2014-08-28 07:00:31',35.2,56.0,35.3,0.0000000,0
6,1,'2014-08-28 07:00:31',35.2,56.0,35.2,0.0000000,0
```

And here's the .csv for the file that doesn't work:

```
60135,1,'2014-08-28 15:19:19',52,68.3,52.6,0.43186,0
60136,1,'2014-08-28 15:19:20',56.9,71.6,51.3,0.43186,0
60137,1,'2014-08-28 15:19:20',56.5,68.8,58.3,0.43186,0
60138,1,'2014-08-28 15:19:21',57,70.1,56.4,0.43186,0
60139,1,'2014-08-28 15:19:21',56.5,69.2,56.2,0.43186,0
60140,1,'2014-08-28 15:19:22',58.7,71.4,56.7,0.43186,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only loads the first row then it is not detecting the line endings properly.  I suggest using a hex editor to check what line endings you have in your source file.

Perhaps you saved as "CSV (Macintosh)" which uses \r as line endings instead.  If this is the case, you should be able to use

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'";
```

### A more generic solution if you dont know the line endings...

MySQL has no automatic line ending detection and that is why you have to tell it how to parse the data.  You can use this short function to do some basic frequency analysis.

```
function detectLineEndings($file)
{
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    $le_linux = substr_count($data, "\n");
    $le_windows = substr_count($data, "\r\n");
    $le_mac = substr_count($data, "\r");

    if ($le_linux > $le_windows && $le_linux > $le_mac) {
        return '\n';
    }
    if ($le_mac > $le_linux && $le_mac > $le_windows) {
        return '\r';
    }
    return '\r\n';
}

$endings = detectLineEndings($target_file);

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $target_file . "' 
        INTO TABLE " . $file_name . "
        FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '''' TERMINATED BY ','
        LINES TERMINATED BY '" . $endings ."'";
```

Comment: That was what was wrong! Cool...how can I catch both the `'\r'` and `'\n'` for files coming from Windows and Macs? It doesn't work with `'\r\n'`

Comment: Windows uses **\r\n**, Mac uses **\r**, so **\r\n** wont work with mac csv files.  If **\r** is also not working with windows csv files, then you need to detect it first.  I have added a function to the answer to help you.